# В .htaccess не работает только 1 RewriteRule параметр, а если добавить второй, то перестает работать первый! Что делать?

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Вот код эти строки:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /game.php?id=$1&href=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /product.php?type=$1&category=$2 [L]
```

Comment: У вас не верно, все что только можно представить... Логика полностью отсутствует, у вас 2 одинаковых правила сопоставления, второе правило ни когда не выполниться, ибо оно равно первому.

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо четко разделять правила между собой.
В строке сопоставления нужно иметь префикс или набор вариантов.

```
RewriteRule ^game/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /game.php?id=$1&href=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /product.php?type=$1&category=$2 [L]
```

Comment: для 1 используется ссылка: game.php?id=2783158&href=free
для 2: product.php?type=category&category=igra